# How to remove all child element (span), from its parent (h3)?

Tags: java, html, css

I am trying to replicate the window calculator which has a main display plus an upper display with the history of the digits inserted.

When you press "equal" the history (all tha spans) are supposed to be removed.

I tired with the following but it removes all the span except the last two:

```
 let i;
      for(i = 0; i < upperDisplay.childNodes.length; i++) {
        upperDisplay.removeChild(upperDisplay.childNodes[i]);
      }
```

upperDisplay is the parent element

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably meant to use `ParentNode.children` instead of `.childNodes`, as `.childNodes` also includes e.g. TextNodes rather than only "actual" HTML-Elements.

The problem is best explained using a simple example:

Say we have an array with 10 elements, and print the length of the array in each step for as many elements as it has:

```js
var array = [,,,,,,,,,,];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  console.log(array.length);
}
```

And now, let's remove one element in each iteration:

```js
var array = [,,,,,,,,,,];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  array.splice(i, 1);
  console.log(array.length);
}
```

As we can see in the console, we are reducing the length of the array, shifting the entries to the front without taking this into consideration with our iteration-variable `i`.
Since `i` is increased and `array.length` decreased by one each step, we are only able to reach half (rounded down) of all elements when iterating with an increment.

How do we fix this?
Instead of starting at zero and incrementing `i`, we can start at `array.length` and decrement `i`, together with `array.length` (since removing an element effectively decrements `array.length`). That way, we will technically always access the last element of the array, like this:

```js
var array = [,,,,,,,,,,];

for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; --i) {
  array.splice(i, 1);
  console.log(array.length);
}
```

**Note** that the *for...of*-loop and the `Array.forEach()` are faulty the same way an incremental *for*-loop is.